# According the background color with the role Jhipster

Tags: angular, jhipster

I want to switch the background color with the different authorities.
Example, if the admin is connect, the background color is red.

I know it is a simple case but i'm new on Jhipster and I don't understand how can i do that.

(I'm using Angular 9 for the front-end)

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at navbar.component.ts and navbar.component.html to see how some menus are disabled depending on user's authorithies. You can use similar approach to change CSS class

Comment: Can we use the jhiHasAnyAutority and ngstyle together?

Comment: No but you can read how jhiHasAnyAutority is implemented and call AccountService within a function of your component that you will use in ngStyle or ngClass

Comment: I have some strange thing. When I'm connecting with the admin account and do "console.log(this.accountService.isAuthenticated());", it says "false". But     this.accountService.identity(true).subscribe(e=>console.log(e));
shows the currentUser. Do u have any idea?

Comment: This is normal because identity() returns an Observable while isAuthenticated()  returns immediately. If you are not very familiar with RxJs and Observable, I suggest you invest some time to learn it, it won't be wasted time.

Comment: My question, is why I have false for the isAuthenticated if i have a currentUser. Sorry, wasnt clear

Comment: Have you checked that your code is called when you think it should? Asynchronism is hard sometimes and you must verify your assumptions. Anyway, you have an example of using isAuthenticated in home.component.ts and home.component.html, this is what you need to do.